# T-SQL STRING_SPLIT to get first and last item from array

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2019

Given someone's full name, I'm trying to use STRING_SPLIT to get the firstname and lastname.

From Microsoft, STRING_SPLIT is used like this:

```sql
DECLARE @tags NVARCHAR(400) = 'clothing,road,,touring,bike'

SELECT value
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tags, ',')
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '';
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

But **value** wasn't declared anywhere.

I've been playing with this *"new to me"* STRING_SPLIT function, but I can't get it to work as it seems like it should.

```sql
declare @fullname varchar(255), @first varchar(50), @last varchar(50);
set @fullname='Lisa Simpson Chespirito';
select @first, @last from string_split(@fullname, ' ');
```

But, my unexpected output is:

```
(No column name) | (No column name)
NULL             | NULL
NULL             | NULL
```

Aside from "Why aren't my values being assigned?", I'd also like to know why 2 rows are returned.

There is also the **ordinal** property:

> If the enable_ordinal argument is passed a value of 1, a second column named ordinal is returned that consists of the 1-based index values of each substring's position in the input string. The return type is bigint.

Let's assume that **value** is a property that I can access. Can I somehow use **ordinal** to selectively pick the first and last items from **value**?

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
set @first=value(1);
set @last=value(value.length);
```

That isn't working, though.

How would I do this?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If you're not on 2022+ then `STRING_SPLIT` will be useless to you.

Comment: *But, my unexpected output is:* ... that output though is **exactly** what I would expect, you're selecting the values of your undefined variables, so of course you're seeing NULL - why wouldn't you? Try selecting `value` to see the output from String_split

Comment: *why 2 columns are returned.* - because you're selecting `@first, @last` - that's two columns

Comment: @ThomA Microsoft SQL Server 2019, but split_string is working

Comment: @Stu grammar aside, how do I assign values to `@first` and `@last`?

Comment: @podrick I'm not questioning any grammer? You will need to determine which row is first and which is last; whilst you might "get away with it" in versions prior to 2022, the outout of string_split is not guaranteed to return rows in a specific order (like any table in a RDBMS) - you'd need 2022's ordinal_position. For a production system I'd suggest to use one of the many other string_split methods you can Google for. And also it appears to me, from the code you've shown, you *may* not have a fundamental grasp of sets and how a table-valued function works.

Comment: @podrick Only SQL Server 2022 provides the order of items. In SQL Server 2019 you can split but there's no way to determine the order

Comment: Aside: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only SQL Server 2022 provides the order of items. In previous versions you have to use string manipulation to retrieve specific items.

Finding the first item is easy: find the first `,` and take the characters up to it:

```
select left(@tags,charindex(',',@tags)-1) as first
```

There's no function that returns the last index of a character. One way to do this is to reverse the text before searching

```
select 
    left(@tags,charindex(',',@tags)-1) as first,
    RIGHT(@tags, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@tags)) - 1) as last
```

Comment: Would you have to do another reverse to avoid something like 'htimS' for Smith?

Comment: @JosephDoggie No, the `RIGHT()` function is using the original `@tags` value, it's only the position that  uses the reversed string (`@tags`) to find the last delimiter.

Comment: @AlanShofield Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

> Given someone's full name, I'm trying to ... get the firstname and lastname.

You have *no idea* the can of works this is opening. Names are *not a solved problem*, and there are so many edge cases it can make your head spin.

But pressing forward into the abyss anyway, this will work for the basic example in the question and the most common variation:

```
declare @fullname varchar(255), @first varchar(50), @last varchar(50);
set @fullname='Lisa Simpson Chespirito';

WITH base As (
                                 -- trick the required "order by" into a valid expression that doesn't actually do anything
    select value, row_number() over (order by case when value=value then 1 end) rn
    from string_split(@fullname, ' ')
) 
                           -- coalesce in case there is no middle name present
select @first = b1.value, @last = coalesce(nullif(rtrim(b3.value),''), b2.value) 
from base b1 
-- manual pivot
join base b2 on b2.rn = 2
join base b3 on b3.rn = 3
where b1.rn = 1

select @first, @last
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/BPPpAAnE

But personally I'd do everything in my power to *avoid actually using this.* Instead, I would look **hard** at handling this data better on the front end, at the point where it's captured. I'd even look at a simple application to have an actual human do manual review of these before letting this just rip though significant data.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to cite a reference showing that using `row-number` with `string_split` will _guarantee_ the correct order of the rows returned from `string_split`? The SQL Server 2022 documentation for [`string_split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) says "The output rows might be in any order. The order _isn't_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string."

Comment: @HABO Rows Yes, rows _might_ be in any order, but as a practical matter the function is implemented in a way and so I'd turn the tables here: can you find a case where SQL Server actually changes this? I mean, sure-- if you have joins to other data, then SQL Server may re-order things to match indexes on those other tables, but otherwise it's not gonna move things around just to mess with you.